# Access parent index in nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to do this really basic example :

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
<li ng-repeat="config in configs">
    <span >Config : {{config}}</span>
    <li ng-repeat="version in versions">
        {{config}}
    </li>
</li>
</div>
```

So basically, I got 2 imbricated `ng-repeat` loop, and I would like to access a value of the first loop from the second one.
I thought it was really basic, but no way to make it work. My result of that is 1 `li`with the config printed, and 3 empty sub `li`s 
I already tried a lot of combination list `{{$parent.index}}`, `{{$parent.config}}` etc ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this has to do with the structure of your HTML.

[Here is a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D37Ebi?p=preview).

Since you are omitting the `<ul>` tags that are required for lists.  The nested `<li>` is causing a display issue.

I have simple wrapped the `<li>` with `<ul>` and it seems to work fine:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="config in configs">
    <span >Config : {{ config }}</span>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="version in versions">
          VersionConfig: {{ config }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It was not angular, but HTML, that was not allowing the content to be displayed.